# Certainty Equivalence and Probability Premium (intuition)

Tags: intuition, decision-theory, risk

I just wanted to ask a simple question: what is the difference between certainty equivalent of a lottery F() and probability premium? They are both concepts in analyzing risk aversion, and I understand that the certainty equivalent c(F,u) is an amount of money x. But what about probability premium? The definition only mentions "the excess in winning probability over fair odds that makes the individual indifferent between the certain outcome X and a gamble between the two outcomes". But what is this "excess" in units? Is it also in monetary terms or utility?

Comment: Can you provide some context for this? Eg, perhaps a link to where you see these definitions?

Comment: I got this from the book by Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green (Microeconomic Theory), page 186.